# How does Play integrity api assures Genuine app binary

Tags: android, patching, frida

I discovered that we can use the Play integrity api instead of safetynet now to assure the integrity off an app that is running. I am wondering if people have a way of bypassing the "Genuine app binary"-aspect of this method.
I could not find much information on how they check if the app is modified or not.

I would like to evaluate how secure it really is. Because if you would for example send a hash of your apk with your integrity api request, then the app could be patched to just send the correct hash value I think. Or does this login happen in the google play services?

Comment: In theory, it can be bypassed. An actor can replicate the behaviour of the client-side integrity component and fool the server into thinking the client binary is legitimate. Whether it's something that's going to be done in practice depends on the effectiveness of the implementation and whether it's worth doing for the actor.